# QTP (Siebel) which field in list applet is activated?

Tags: field, qtp, siebel

when I press a "New" button in list applet, there appeared new row with activated particular field,
I need to check, if correct field is activated.

The question is: how to know which field in list applet is active now?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't noticed this: .GetActiveControlName

Comment: This is answer to my question